# passing userspace buffer to kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to compare the performance when we copy `skb` from kernel to userspace using DMA and normal `skb_copy_datagram_iovec()`. I create a module to test. May anyone show me how we can create a big buffer from userspace and pass it to my module (as `tcp_recvmsg()` is passed an iovec from userspace). Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Write a Linux character device driver and implement the writev method. For details check out Linux Device Drivers latest edition.